# Why does SPTD.SYS not load _unless_ the modem powered-up, and link active?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bsod, power, modem

This is similar to [SPTD.sys (from Daemon Tools) kills my boot (Win XP Media Center Edition)](https://superuser.com/questions/95367/sptd-sys-from-daemon-tools-kills-my-boot-Windows-XP-media-center-edition)

Over the last few weeks, I've been subject to frequent power-outages.

When my computer P4-1.7 2GB running Windows XP Pro experiences a power-outage whilst connected to the internet, I can not boot normally, using last known good configuration, or even into safe-mode. All attempts fail with a message to the effect that SPTD.SYS cannot be loaded. There are no SCSI components installed that I'm aware of ...

**Boot succeeds only after the modem is also powered up, and link is active.**

Why can SPTD.SYS not be loaded without the modem powered-up, and link active?

Comment: I would boot from an Ubuntu CD and delete the sptd.sys driver, see if it will boot now, if it does uninstall daemon tools using revo uninstaller Free version....http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Comment: Not quite the answer to the question; My question is why does the modem need to be powered up, and the internet-link active for SPTD to load successfully?

Comment: Some file or driver scrambled when the power was cut, you may never figure out why, move on and fix it is my suggestion. If you don't solve the power issue it will cause other problems down the road, I suggest you invest in a quality UPS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Windows kernel expert, but this may shed some light or lead to a possible explanation:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115486

Some drivers are known as "boot-time" drivers and load before Windows starts.  The article explains how it's necessary to support the notion that some drivers can load before others.  Quoting from the KB article:

"...device drivers with a start value of 0 load before any device drivers with a start value of 1 attempt to load. "

So, did you install a disc that came with your modem?  Perhaps it installed some type of security driver that is failing to load for some reason.  An antivirus program could also do this.